# Android 9 - Pie chmod issue

Tags: android, android-permissions

I have used "**adb push**" to copy a file to the **/sdcard** directory on my android device. I can not give it executable permissions (**chmod +x**) because of this issue.
As far as I can see **/sdcard** is the only directory the adb user has write permissions on.

Is there a directory that has both **chmod** and **write** capabilities?
Thanks

btw I tried to connect adb as root **sudo adb root**
but I received the error message: **adbd cannot run as root in production builds**

Answer (score 0):

I think there is not.
Chmod is equaled to mount/remount commands by permission point of view. Mount/remount requires root access. You don't have root rights because you have production build.
So, on the build you will not be able to find any directory with needed rights.

Btw, why do you want to use chmod +x? Usually all executable files for android are in system and in vendor but not on sdcard.